# Recarregar Dados na UITableview usando Firebase

Tags: firebase, swift, xcode, uitableview

Estou usando uma tabela customizada, que recupera dados do `Firebase`. Mas ela só atualiza, os dados novos, se eu fechar o app e abrir novamente, mesmo inserindo o `reloadData()` na tabela.

**Exemplo:** A tabela está sem nenhum elemento, quando é adicionado um novo elemento por uma outra ViewController, eu volto para checar a tabela, e esse novo elemento aparece. 
Quando é adicionado o segundo elemento, na tabela aparece duplicado (duas vezes esse segundo elemento), mas se eu verificar no Firebase, `os nós`  não estão duplicado. 
Então eu preciso fechar o aplicativo, e logo em seguida, com ele aberto os elementos estão atualizados na tabela, é como se o `reloadData` não estivesse sendo recarregando.

O que preciso fazer ou que estou fazendo de errado?

```
 func exibeAtrasado(){

     tvAtrasados.register(UINib(nibName: "OnAtrasados", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "OnAtrasados")

     let database = Database.database().reference().child("OAtrasado")

     database.observe(DataEventType.value) { (snapshot) in

         if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {

             for onAtrasado in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {

                 let onsObject = onAtrasado.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                 let data = onsObject?["data"]
                 let horario = onsObject?["horário"]
                 let linha = onsObject?["linha"]
let onibAtr = ConfiguracaoOnAtrasados(horario: horario as! String, linha: linha as! String, data: data as! String)

                 self.onb.append(onibAtr)


             }

                 self.tvAtrasados.reloadData()

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consegui corrigir o erro da duplicidade. **Mas o erro ainda persiste na questão de atualização**. Se eu fizer a exclusão `do nó`, direto no `Firebase` a os elementos ainda continuam na tabela. Eu preciso fechar o app para poder atualizar a tabela

Antigo

```
database.observe(DataEventType.value) { (snapshot)
```

Novo

```
  database.observe(DataEventType.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
```

Antigo

```
for onAtrasado in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
```

Novo

```
let onAtrasado = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
```

Antigo

```
   let onsObject = onAtrasado.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                 let data = onsObject?["data"]
                 let horario = onsObject?["horário"]
                 let linha = onsObject?["linha"]
```

Novo

```
         let data = onAtrasado?["data"]
         let horario = onAtrasado?["horário"]
         let linha = onAtrasado?["linha"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Usei o método `childRemoved` do `Firebase` para escutar o nó que eu excluo. Utilizei também uma `UIRefreshControl()` para que o usuário possa atualizar os `dados da tableView`.

```
     var refreshTable = UIRefreshControl()
         @objc func refresh(_ sender: Any){

                    self.tabeladeDados.reloadData()
                    self.refreshTable.endRefreshing()

            } 
         database.observe(DataEventType.childRemoved, with: { (snapshot) in {

var indice = 0
            for i in self.dados {
                if i.uuid == snapshot.key {
                    self.dados.remove(at: indice)
                    print(i.uuid)
                 self.refreshTable.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Atualizando...")
                        self.refreshTable.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.refresh), for: .valueChanged)
                        self.tabeladeDados.addSubview(self.refreshTable)
       }
    }
```